# Kubernetes AWS deployment can not set docker credentials

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I set up a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using kube-up script with one master and two minions. I want to create a pod that uses a private docker image. So I need to add my credential to docker daemons of each minion of the cluster. But I don't know how to log into the minions created by AWS script. What is the recommended way to pass credentials to the docker demons of each minion?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best method for you is `ImagePullSecrets` - you will create secret (docker config), which be will be used for image pull. Read more about different concepts of using private registry http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#using-a-private-registry

Answer (score 0):

Explained here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

There are 3 options for ImagePullPolicy: Always, IfNotPresent and Never

1) example of yaml:

...
spec:
containers:
    - name: uses-private-image
      image: $PRIVATE_IMAGE_NAME
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [ "echo", "SUCCESS" ]

2) By default, the kubelet will try to pull each image from the specified registry. However, if the imagePullPolicy property of the container is set to **IfNotPresent** or **Never**, then a local image is used (preferentially or exclusively, respectively).

If you want to rely on pre-pulled images as a substitute for registry authentication, you must ensure all nodes in the cluster have the same pre-pulled images.

This can be used to preload certain images for speed or as an alternative to authenticating to a private registry.

All pods will have read access to any pre-pulled images.